# What does it mean when the value in the HI Register is minus one (-1)?

Tags: mips

The MIPS multiply hardware stores the 64 bit product in 2 registers, HI and LO, What does it mean when the value in the HI Register is minus one (-1)?

Answer (score 0):

The signed value `-1` corresponds binary value `1111...111` (all ones) in A2 complement.
You should get familiar with [A2 complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

In such representation:

- Positive integers are represented with a leading `0` (in the most significant bit) followed by the binary representation of the integer.
- Negative integers are represented by applying A1 complement (that is, negate the binary representation of the absolute value of the integer and then adding one). In this case the most significant bit becomes 1.

By negating the binary representation of the absolute value of an integer, the number's leading `0`s of the binary representation become `1`s.

Therefore, if `HI` has a signed value `-1` it means that it has all `1s` (reading them in binary format). Thus, you can tell it's representing a negative number (the most significant bit is 1). In this particular case, the signed number gets stored in `LO`.